# perl, iterate over XML

Tags: xml, perl

I have XML,

```
<queue>
   <user>1</user>
   <user>2</user>
   <user>3</user>
</queue>
```

I'm trying to iterate over it so to get each value of `user`

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
my $xml = "<queue><user>1</user><user>2</user></queue>";

my $xml_obj = XMLin($xml, forcearray => 1);

my $users = $xml_obj->{'queue'};

foreach my $v (@users){
        print $v;
}
```

I've tried forcing & non-forcing the array, i've also tried just skipping the `queue` stanza, and defining `$users` as `$xml_obj->{'user'}`, however all of these either return undefined index warnings, or empty results;

Comment: Don't use XML::Simple. It's much better that way!

Comment: Not my choice i'm afraid, developing on existing script (that does seem to be the common answer though)

Comment: OK. I'll hopefully shed some light on your problem, but I really would urge using a different XML parser. Most support backward compatibility with XML::Simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egrantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) is a nasty library that really needs to go and die. It coerces XML into perl-like data structures, but does so in a way that means you lose data in the process, and have to guess to convert it back. (It often guesses right, but not always, which is why you get all that nonsense with force array, etc.)

That's why it says in the docs:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces

I would strongly urge you to consider another XML library instead. [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eshlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0122/LibXML.pod) or [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm) - I like the latter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml_str = '<queue>
   <user>1</user>
   <user>2</user>
   <user>3</user>
</queue>';

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parse ( $xml_str ); 

foreach my $user ( $twig -> root -> children('user') ) {
   print $user -> text,"\n";
}
```

Note too - `XML::Twig` has the `simplify` method:

> `simplify (%options)`
>
> Return a data structure suspiciously similar to XML::Simple's. Options are identical to XMLin options, see XML::Simple doc for more details (or use DATA::dumper or YAML to dump the data structure)

Which can make it much easier to 'sneak in'.

However given your example - all you're missing is `use strict;` `use warnings;` and the thing that would have told you about:

> Global symbol "@users" requires explicit package name

E.g.:

And you need to print your object - it is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'user' => [
                    '1',
                    '2'
                  ],
          'queue' => {}
        };
```

Note how `XML::Simple` has put `queue` as a separate hash key - `user` is being treated as an array within the same parent element. (Which is just one of the gotchas of `XML::Simple`).

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = "<queue><user>1</user><user>2</user></queue>";

my $xml_obj = XMLin($xml, forcearray => 1);

my $users = $xml_obj->{'user'};

foreach my $v (@$users){
        print $v;
}
```

Note - also dereferences `$users` into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to do:

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
my $xml = "<queue><user>1</user><user>2</user></queue>";

my $xml_obj = XMLin($xml);

print Dumper($xml_obj);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'user' => [
                    '1',
                    '2'
                  ]
        };
```

But XML::Simple is terrible + I kinda get the feeling this is a homework.